# Restoring Files from Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am using eclipse Luna.  All of a sudden half of my code (files) are missing from my workspace.  All of my class are missing from packages, now i left out with few lies of code thats it. It would be help full if any one let me know how to recover my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Eclipse's local history. Right click on the file then replace with previous from Local History.

Comment: manually browse to `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history/`. see what's there.